# Function that continuous at each a perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f:(2,3)\to \Bbb R$ be a function with dense graph such that for each $x\in (2,3)$ there exist a perfect set $P$ having $x$ as bilateral limit point, that is $x$ is a limit point of $(-\infty,x)\cap P$ and $(x,\infty)\cap P,$ $f\restriction P$ is continuous at $x.$  I want to extent to $f_1\colon [2,3]\to \Bbb R$ and make sure $f_1$ has the same property as $f.$ My thought process is that We need to ensure the property perceived at $2$ and $3$.

Now, I stared with decreasing sequence $s_n$ and choose a perfect set $P_n\subset(s_{n+1},s_n)$ and then put $P=\bigcup_{n<\omega}P_n\cup \{2\}.$ Of course, $P$ is a perfect set and has $2$ is limit point of $(2,\infty)\cap P.$ Still need to prove the continuity, that is, $f\restriction P$ is continuous at $2.$ Here was I have difficulty. I think I need to choose $P_n$'s more careful. Any help will be a hug help

Comment: @RobArthan, Good catch. You are right. Is it clear now

Comment: Yes. It's clear now.

Comment: @RobArthan, Do u have an idea ?